# SQL Command Syntax Error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I definitely regret asking such a simple question, but it's been driving me off the wall, and I'm not sure if it's because of an update or anything. But can anyone tell me what the error with the following SQL statement is?

```
$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendarevents WHERE 'EventMonth'="January" AND 'EventDay'="1"")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: look at placement of quotes....

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work better, using correct quotes and backticks, please have a look at the query

```
$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendarevents WHERE `EventMonth`= 'January' AND `EventDay`= 1 ")
```

**SIDENOTE:**

Please consider using [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**mysqli_**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql_* functions.

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

`$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendarevents WHERE`EventMonth`='January' AND`EventDay`='1'")
or die(mysql_error());`

The way that you have used double quotes (") is the first and the biggest of issues, and you should use backticks(`) instead of single quotes(') for escaping table and column names in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use double quotes ["] inside of a sql statement.

january and 1 need to be in single quotes instead of double.

You also don't need quotes around the field names.

```
"SELECT * FROM calendarevents WHERE 'EventMonth'="January" AND 'EventDay'="1""
```

should be

```
"SELECT * FROM calendarevents WHERE EventMonth='Januay' AND EventDay='1'"
```

Comment: Yes, you *can* use double quotes within a SQL statement. It's true that we prefer to use single quotes to enclose string literals, but MySQL allows double quotes for string literals (if `SQL_MODE` of the session doesn't include `ANSI_QUOTES`.) OP "syntax problem" is issue with PHP double quoted strings, NOT a SQL syntax problem. (PHP allows for double quotes to be escaped. As you point out, don't enclose identifiers in single quotes (within a SQL statement) because it will be interpreted as a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `calendarevents` WHERE `EventMonth`="January" AND `EventDay`=1")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: indeed you should switch to PDO...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM calendarevents WHERE EventMonth='January' AND EventDay = '1'";
$iname = mysql_query($query);
```